# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot create temp directory: /sd card/1339054625829.

Tags: android, junit, sd-card

I am trying to automate android (Running Basic test) using selenium on the Android emulator using *Junit*, I have added all required jars to Classpath, Started Emulator, Opened the Web Driver on it and Set up port forwarding.

But when I run the Test in Eclipse(Run as JUnit Test). It fails and I get an Error:

`org.openqa.selenium.webdriverexception: cannot create temp directory: /sd card/1339054625829`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get this error if you have not setup any space for SD card when you start the emulator. You can set the amount of memory to be used as device SD card memory. You can find this when you edit AVD details

[image]

Comment: but i have phone without sd card. is there a way to use phones internal storage?

Comment: @iTake it doesnt matter whether your phone has SD card or not. This setting is in the emulator and not in phone. Emulator runs on PC

Comment: @A.J i know. but i get the very same error message on real phone, when it has no SD card

Comment: @iTake ah ok. I have not worked on a phone which doesn't have SD card. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

The following steps fix the problem for me on a real device (with or without sd card):

1. Connect your USB
2. Open the additional USB settings (On Android->swipe down from the top of your screen)
3. Select Media device or portal and Tools